# Programmatically Constraint Button

Tags: swift, xcode, button

i  would like my button to remain centered on the x axis but i would like to adjust it on the y axis. my button is programmatically made but my sign up page is mostly constructed on storyboard. Which is making the button look off from everything else

```
 super.viewDidLoad()


    button = dropDownBtn.init(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width:0, height: 0))
    button.setTitle("BusinessType", for: .normal)
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    self.view.addSubview(button)

    PROBLEM !!!!!
    //button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    //button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true

    button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200).isActive = true
    button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
    button.self.layer.cornerRadius = 10

    button.dropView.dropDownOptions = ["Apparel", "Artist", "Beauty", "Cosmetology", "Fitness", "Resturant","Photography"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Re comment `centerXAnchor` and `centerYAnchor` constraints

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
  button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor,constant:-200), 
  button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
  button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40) 
])
```

Comment: i  still can't adjust the button upward

Comment: where exactly you want it to be ? can you replace `centerYAnchor` with `topAnchor` or best a design screenshot

Comment: right now my button is perfectly centered in the middle of the screen , i   don't want that .... instead i   would like to move the button up on the y axis while still keeping it perfectly centered on the x-axis

Comment: ok try edit add constant `self.view.centerYAnchor,constant:-200),`